# I Cant Seem To Figure Out MessageEmbedVideo

Tags: discord.js

Does Anyone Know How To Use MessageEmbedVideo

I Keep On Using [Discord.js/MessageEmbedVideo](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/MessageEmbedVideo) But It Does Not Understand

[Im Trying To Achieve This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wS2Is.png)

Comment: What are you trying? What is happening that you don’t want?

Comment: I'm Trying To Achieve This https://i.stack.imgur.com/wS2Is.png

Comment: I mean what code are you trying, and what is the result of that that you don’t want?

Comment: Ok The Problem is [Disc ord.js](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/MessageEmbedVideo) Because It My Console Log Says `        const Embed = new Discord.MessageEmbedVideo()
                      ^

`